# How do I solve this reference error?

Tags: javascript

I understand if it was a variable I could have used the var but as its a function, how do I define `baz`.

```
var foo = "bar";

function bar() {
    var foo = "baz";

    function baz(foo) {
        foo = "bam";
        bam = "yay";
    }

    baz();
}

baz();
```

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? In JavaScript, each function has its own scope. Since `baz` is defined inside `bar`, it's not accessible outside of it.

Comment: but is there a way i can access it

Comment: Did the solution I posted work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is an approach that works for you, but you can make `baz` an attribute of `bar` and you can call it when you make a new instance of `bar`.

```
var foo = "bar";

function bar() {
    var foo = "baz";

    this.baz = function(foo) {
        foo = "bam";
        bam = "yay";
    }

    this.baz();
}

new bar().baz();
```